# Session variables not available outside of session class

Tags: php, session

I'm trying to figure out why my session variables are not carrying over to my other php pages. I created a session class that controls the login state based on the `_Session` and generates the `_Sessions` variable as well. Whenever I check the class, it say the `_Session` variables are set, but if I try to use `$_Session[key]` on other php pages I get blank values. Can someone tell me why?

session class:

```
class Session{
private $bLoggedIn = false;

function __construct(){
    session_start();
    $this->checkLogin();
    if(isset($_POST['bLogOut'])){
        $this->logOut();
    }
}

public function isLoggedIn($sUser){
    return $this->bLoggedIn();
}

public function logIn($sTable, $sUserName, $sPassword){
    if($this->bLoggedIn){
        return 'Already logged in.';
    } else{
        $queryResults = makeLoginRequest($sTable, $sUserName, $sPassword);
        $_SESSION['user_Id'] = $queryResults[0]['user_Id'];
        $_SESSION['password'] = $queryResults[0]['password'];
        $_SESSION['firstName'] = $queryResults[0]['firstName'];
        $_SESSION['lastName'] = $queryResults[0]['lastName'];
        $_SESSION['start'] = time();
        $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + 1800;
        $this->bLoggedIn = true;
        return $queryResults[0];
    }
}

public function logOut(){
    session_destroy();
    $this->bLoggedIn = false;
    echo 'Successfully logged out.';
}

public function checkLogin(){
    if(isset($_SESSION['user_Id'])){
        $this->bLoggedIn = true;
        return $this->bLoggedIn;
    } else{
        $this->bLoggedIn = false;
        return $this->bLoggedIn;
    }
}
}
```

request class(this is the class where I try to get the session variable values and get empty values returned):

```
class request{
private $iUserId;
private $sPassword;
private $sFirstName;
private $sLastName;

public function __construct($sService, $oData, $iAffectedUserId){
    $session = new Session();
    // The four values below are empty because the $_SESSION variables are empty
    $this->iUserId = $_SESSION['user_Id'];
    $this->sPassword = $_SESSION['password'];
    $this->sFirstName = $_SESSION['firstName'];
    $this->sLastName = $_SESSION['lastName'];
    switch($sService){
        case 'follower':
            $this->requestFollower();
            break;
        case 'followee':
            $this->requestFollowee();
            break;
        case 'promoter':
            $this->requestPromoter();
            break;
        case 'promotee':
            $this->requestPromotee();
            break;
        case 'note':
            $this->requestNote();
            break;
        case 'createFollowee':
            $this->createFollowee();
            break;
        case 'createPromotee':
            $this->createPromotee();
            break;
        case 'createNote':
            $this->$sNote = $oData;
            $this->createNote($iAffectedUserId, $this->sNote);
            break;
        case 9:
            break;
        case 1:
            break;
        default:
            echo "ErrorCode: 4000";
            break;
    }
}
}
```

Again, I checked the session variables in the session class and they are set.

Comment: Has the session been started on subsequent pages?

Comment: Shouldn't you call the checkLogin() method before trying to access the $_SESSION anyway?

Comment: @DavidJones I did, I just remove to save on code space here. That's how I know that the session variable are set.

Comment: oh ok, to be safe I always start my session at the first line of my application to make sure it always gets set without issue. Might be worth taking it out of the constructor and placing it where ever the script begins

Comment: @DavidJones I was reading about session.save_path and now I'm starting to think that might be the problem. It said to change the path to something not in the document root directory. I'm using xampp to host. 
Path I set: C:\xampp\session
I believe this is root dir: C:\xampp\htdocs
Did I set it right or do I need to change again?

Comment: sorry im not sure, i have never used that before

Comment: I nuked the file and wrote it again and everything started working. I'm not sure why that worked but it did.

Answer (score 1):

Move `session_start();` in really early in your class files, not in the constructor.
Also add it to your first line of request class (if you are not using namespace).

In your session class, and everywhere where you want to start a session, you can check, is there a session already.

```
if (!session_id()) {
   session_start();
}

class Session{
private $bLoggedIn = false;
....
```

remove the session_start from the constructor.

Do the same in the request. 
It's start a session if it's not started.

Comment: either this, or include the session class file in your request class file

Comment: @AresDraguna I already had require_once('Session.php') as the first line in the request php file. Does it have to be in the actually class?

Comment: @lolka_bolka The session_start() is working in the constructor, but even if it's working does it still not matter?

Comment: if you are using sessions in request.php (let's say this is the name of the file where you have class request) then yes, because there is where you initialize your session. You cannot use session vars without having the session initialized. and if this is the case, you can see it in your server error.log file, you will defenently have some warnings there

Comment: @AresDraguna Yes, when I add session_start() I got a message. I got ' A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()' So I shouldn't need it because the session has been started right?

Comment: in this case, yes... if you requested the file and got that message it means that the session already started... funny... I have to leave my office now, I will try to answer this tomorrow if someone does not answer it by then :)

Comment: check my edited answer. Or, if you want to keep your structure, you can use this if condition everywhere to be sure, session start only, if you do not have.